# How to get Torch browser to stop prompting me to update to new version?

Tags: macos, web-browser

I have the Torch browser (Version 29.0.0.7181 (7181)) installed on my Mac (10.11.4). It's no longer updated or supported on the Mac but I use it as a tester browser for some things so I like it.

But Torch periodically asks me to install a new version of Torch. There's a modal window that says:

```
A new version of Torch is available.
Would you like to install it now?
"Remind me later"      "Install now"
```

I have to click the "Remind me later" to dismiss it. And if I click "Install now" nothing happens.

How can I get the Torch browser to stop prompting me to update to a new version? There is no new version. There is nothing in the Torch settings to disable this. Is the prompter a binary I can just delete from my Mac? Anyway at all to disable this annoying dialog from ever appearing again?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a buggy application that's no longer supported. Soon, as your browser gets more and more out of date, you'll be at greater risk for security issues and malware. It's much safer (less annoying, and probably easier too) if you start using a modern, supported browser. Take your pick between Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Vivaldi.

Comment: @John-Ramos That is true and sound advice. But I use Torch on the Mac **only** for local testing of my dev web sites so always at IPs like: 192.168.1.*.  I'd like to know if there is a "Torch Helper" app like there is for the "Google Chrome Helper" that does that popup and it is possible to disable it in some manner via the Torch app or some OSX setting/hack.

Comment: I added an answer, let me know what following it does.

Comment: Also what if you try hiding the window with the update prompt, as if it were a browser window you were hiding?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down on this site (http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Torch-5557-program.aspx) and you'll see something that's known to come with Torch called `torchhelper.dll`.

I dug into Activity Monitor to gather data about Chrome (I really don't want to download Torch) and found all this when expanding the Chrome app section (while using Chrome to bring it up to the top):
[image]

So try this and tell me what happens: open up Activity Monitor on your Mac, go to the Memory tab, then search (top-right) for Torch. Take a screenshot of what comes up! Try killing the processes (tap on whatever helpers come up and press the X in the top left) and see what happens).